# How can I use a neural network in GIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, references

I'd like to learn how to use a neural network in GIS. I surfed in the internet to find good resources or a tutorial about this but I couldn't find any helpful resources. Are there any good references or tutorials about using neural networks in GIS? I'd like to use an [artificial neural network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) (ANN) in mapping hazard zones, for example flood zones or landslides. I use ArcGIS 10 to process the layers but don't know how can  use an ANN.

Comment: to solve what exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Lee and Evangelista (2006)](http://www.nat-hazards-earth-syst-sci.net/6/687/2006/nhess-6-687-2006.pdf) have a good article on earthquake-induced landslide-susceptibility mapping using an artiﬁcial neural network.  They appear to do their GIS analysis in ArcGIS and implement a ANN algorithm in Matlab.

[Spatial Data Modeler (SDM)](http://www.ige.unicamp.br/sdm/default_e.htm) is available as a collection of geoprocessing tools for ArcGIS (earlier Arc 9.x version [here](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15341)). The author describes SDM NN tools as follows:

> The tools include the data-driven methods of Weights of Evidence,
>   Logistic Regression, and two supervised and one unsupervised neural
>   network methods, and a knowledge-driven method Fuzzy Logic.

If you find NNs useful for your projects, I suspect you will want to utilize the functionality of NNs in R.  The following are links to useful sites and packages:

[Overview [technical] article in the R Journal](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-1/RJournal_2010-1_Guenther+Fritsch.pdf)

[Package ‘nnet’](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnet/nnet.pdf)

[Package ‘AMORE’](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AMORE/AMORE.pdf)

[Package ‘neuralnet’](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf)

Comment: thnx @Aaron . their very intersting and helpful